# finding organization and industry/sector from string in dbpedia

Tags: dbpedia, sparqlwrapper, spotlight-dbpedia

I am generating a short list of 10 to 20 strings which I want to lookup on dbpedia to see if they have an organization tag and if so return the industry/sector tag. I have been looking at the SPARQLwrapper queries on their website but am having trouble constructing one that returns organization and sector/industry for my string. Is there a way to do this?

If I use the code below I get a list of industry types I think rather than the industry of the company.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON                                                        

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")                                                                                                                                                       
sparql.setQuery("""                                                                                
   SELECT ?industry  WHERE   
 { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM> a ?industry}             
   """)

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)    
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at queries which are meant to help you understand the querying tool, you should start by looking at the data which is being queried.  For instance, just click http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM, and look at the properties (the left hand column) to see its `rdf:type` values (of which there are MANY)!

Note that IBM is not described as `a ?industry`. IBM is described as `a <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Public_company>` (among other things). On the other hand, IBM is also described as having three values for `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry>` --

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cloud_computing>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Information_technology>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cognitive_computing>
```

I don't know whether these are what you're actually looking for or not, but hopefully what I've done above will start you down the right path to whatever you *do* want to get out of DBpedia.